# How to replace value where "Value Error" arises?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

So I was working when I was using this code:

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

when I had multiple errors like:

```
ValueError: ('Unable to parse string "4.4-1" at position 40064', 'occurred at index UV')
```

Now I have to replace each of the values which are in the above format.

```
data.iloc[r,c]=some value
```

Is there any way one could replace the values with a int/float where the error is raised instead of manually iterating it everytime?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with? presumably `NaN`?

Comment: By a certain integer/float value

Answer (score 2):

You could try with this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: That is possible but it will leave a NaN value which in turn, can be replaced later. I wanted a direct approach to replace it with an int/float number.

Comment: how about adding .fillna("0", inplace = True) at the end?

Comment: do not use `inplace=True`, it will return None, which you then assign to `data`.

Comment: not if you do 'data.fillna("0", inplace = True)' as a next line. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that line in a try/except block.

```
try:
    data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)
except ValueError:
    data = something_else
```

Comment: Can you please specify how to mention the row and column when we were to replace it with an int/float value?

Comment: I don't know anything about Pandas, so I can't help with that.